# sql add dynamical OR to where clause

Tags: sql-server

i need your help again!
my query looks like this

```
Select * from USERS Where username = 'username1';
```

now i want to add some OR to the where clause:

```
Select * from USERS Where username = 'username1' OR username = 'username2';
```

the problem is must generate the query dynamical, because the selected user count is from 1 to 10;

i created a function that adds all user to a string 
output:

```
'username = 'username1' OR username = 'username2''
```

i declare @names

and now my query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @names varchar(1000) = 'username = 'username1' OR  username = 'username2''
Select * from USERS Where @names;
```

what is the right way to some OR's in the where clause?

thank you

Comment: Let me introduce you to the "IN" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: WOW so easy ! thank you Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IN()

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    USERS 
WHERE
    username IN('username1','username2')
```

Comment: Thats it ! Thanks

Comment: @silazzz Wonderful! I'm glad you're on your way. Feel free to "Accept" for future users to find quick answers 

Comment: i will, but i must wait 6 minutes